# Setting up resize event on a QLabel in Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I cannot create a functioning resize event for a custom QT class.

One of the parts of my GUI is a video player. I want the video player to stop playing the video if I'm resizing the GUI. From the forums, I learned that the way to do that is to create a custom QLabel and edit its resize event.

I tried to do it with resizeEvent function and eventFilter function but fail to have it work properly.

My first option was to redesign the resizeEvent. Unfortunately, when I resize my window the resizeEvent is constantly triggered and so I'm stuck in infinite printouts of 'Inside resizeEvent'

```py
class VideoPlayer(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    ResizeSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored, 
                                      QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        self.resize(800, 450)
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.setLineWidth(3)
        self.setText("")
        self.pix = QPixmap()
        self.setPixmap(self.pix)        

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        if not self.pix.isNull():
            print(' Inside resizeEvent')
            self.ResizeSignal.emit(1) # Signal emitted when Qlabel is resized. 
            pixmap = self.pix.scaled(self.width(), self.height(),Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            self.setPixmap(pixmap)
            self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
```

My other option was to try to do the eventFilter option. I commented out resizeEvent and added this function to the class VideoPlayer. However, this is not getting triggered at all when I resize.

```
def eventFilter(self, event):
    if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Resize):
        print( 'Inside event Filter')
        self.ResizeSignal.emit(1)
    return True
```

I would like to learn how to do this properly both ways :) Thanks!

Comment: I did not understand what your goal is, you could explain more that part

Comment: Basically, I want to have a signal emitted when the QLabel is being resized. Currently, It's being emitted non-stop with resizeEvent function OR not emitted at all with eventFilter

Comment: 1) resizeEvent is called in every moment that the size is changed, for that reason it observes that it is called repeatedly, that is the normal behavior. 2) eventFilter is called if you install the filter with `self.installEventFilter(self)`, change `eventFilter(self, event):` to `eventFilter(self, obj, event):`

Comment: Thanks for the response! 1) The problem is that resizeEvent is called even after I am done with resizing. It starts the moment I start resizing and then never stops. 2) That does the trick and it is only called when I actually resize unlike to option (1). However when I add the line `self.installEventFilter(self)`, the pixmap in QLabel dissapears. Any idea why that line would case that?

Comment: 1) Maybe there are many impressions and the console is slow to show it so you can see the print after the resizing is finished. 2) change `return True` to `return super().eventFilter(obj, event)`

Comment: Thanks for the help! The (2) seems to work perfectly now. I don't think that is the issue with (1) though. I waited more than 5 minutes and the console keeps printing out the statement inside `resizeEvent`. Also, I do not observe this behavior with `eventFilter`, which makes me think it has to be something with the reiszeEvent function.

Comment: If you already found a solution it would be great if you post an answer :-)

Comment: Will answer question 2 in abit! Did not realize I can answer my own question here! I would still like to know how to rewrite the resizeEvent function correctly.

Comment: The idea in SO is to contribute to the community, with questions and/or answer

Comment: So I found out that after the first resize, every time I update the Pixmap in QLabel, the resize event is triggered. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: I think so, since if you set a QPixmap the QLabel needs to calculate the size of the QLabel since the minimumSizeHint depends on the QPixmap.

Comment: Any idea on what to do to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem with another issue. Since I resize the label in the resizeEvent function that triggers another resizeEvent and the program gets stuck in the infinite loop. The only way that I found to avoid that is to rewrite the paintEvent in the class.

Here's the code of my new class for anyone interested. The idea was to resize the video while keeping its aspect ratio and emit a signal when I resize it so I can stop my video when the UI is resized.

```
class GameFrame(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    ResizeSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self, width,height):
        super().__init__()  
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        self.setGeometry(0,0,width, height)
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.setLineWidth(3)
        self.setText("")
        self.pix = QPixmap()
        self.setPixmap(self.pix)
        self.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Resize):
            if not self.pix.isNull():                
                pixmap = self.pix.scaled(self.width(), self.height(),Qt.KeepAspectRatio)                  
                if pixmap.width()!=self.width() or pixmap.height()!=self.height():                                        
                    self.ResizeSignal.emit(1)                    
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):        
        if not self.pix.isNull(): 
            size = self.size()
            painter = QPainter(self)
            point = QtCore.QPoint(0,0)
            scaledPix = self.pix.scaled(size, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, transformMode = Qt.FastTransformation)
            # start painting the label from left upper corner
            point.setX((size.width() - scaledPix.width())/2)
            point.setY((size.height() - scaledPix.height())/2)
            painter.drawPixmap(point,scaledPix)

    def changePixmap(self, img):
        self.pix = img
        self.repaint()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @eyllanesc, I was able to answer part 2 of the question.

Changing the `eventFilter` function to this

```
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Resize):
            print( 'Inside event Filter')
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
```

and adding `self.installEventFilter(self)` to the `__init__`, did the trick.

Still trying to figure out why `resizeEvent` keeps being triggered non-stop.